# matching two classes in Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
<ul style="float:left;">
    <li class="font1">sfadsa</li>
    <li class="font2">sfadsa</li>
    <li class="font3">sfadsa</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<ul style="float:right;" >
    <li class="font3">sfadsa</li>
    <li class="font1">sfadsa</li>
    <li class="font2">sfadsa</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have used the jquery scortable option for right ul tags. So if class font 1 matches with the class font1 at the right side then the li tag font should be changed to green in the right li tag and other li tag should be red.Simply if left classes match with right class then the font should change to green. Can anyone help me to do this in jquery ?

Comment: show some jquery code

Comment: You going to close those `<li>`s properly?

Comment: Problem is not so clear: how the li elements are compared? what is compared: class name or text inside li? Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: What do you mean by "if class font 1 matches with the class font1 at the right side"??  Please try to explain more clearly.  Use an example showing how currently it is and what you expect to happen.  Also show any javascript that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

How is this solution? This assumes that each element only ever has one class:

```
$('ul.left li').each(function(i){
  classMatches = $('ul.right li').eq(i).hasClass($(this).attr('class'));
  if(classMatches){
    $('ul.right li').eq(i).add(this).css({color:"#F00"});
  }
});
```

I've also given your `<ul>` classes and applied external CSS styles, firstly to differentiate between the two in jQuery, and secondly, to get rid of your inline styles.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BDIFt)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but maybe you can use it:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="left">
    <ul style="float:left;">
        <li class="font1">sfadsa</li>
        <li class="font2">sfadsa</li>
        <li class="font3">sfadsa</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="right">
    <ul style="float:right;" >
        <li class="font3">sfadsa</li>
        <li class="font1">sfadsa</li>
        <li class="font2">sfadsa</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#right ul').sortable({
    stop : check
});

function check(){
    $('#right li').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('class') == $('#left li:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').attr('class')){
            $(this).css({'background-color':'#0f0'});
        }else{
            $(this).css({'background-color':'#f00'});
        }
    });
}

check();
```

**Demo:**

http://jsbin.com/icepEMa/1

Comment: Hi Andy, Hi, Thanks very much!!! Its works perfect.I used you code its resolves my exact goal.